# Calling Form.Close in Form.Closing

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I've been given the task to clean up an application that my company is using. The previous developer is not working at the company anymore and I have a question.

In a certain form there is a Form.Closing method. In this method some custom code is written. The last line in this method is the `Close();` call. When looking for the source it goes back to `System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close`.

This code sample is visible below:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

    // Some custom code here.

    Close();
}
```

When debugging, when the code arrives at `Close();` it jumps back to the `Form1_Closing` method. This would lead to an endless recursive call ending in a stack overflow. Now, on Windows 7 I sometimes get a stackoverflow error. On Windows 10 this does not happen. Does anyone know why my old colleague has put the `Close` call in the `Closing` method?

If more information is required I will try to provide it. For now I just put the `Close` call in comments and everything appears to be working as before, now also without occasional bugs (stackoverflows) on Windows 7.

Comment: Looks like it's safe to remove that `Close` call.

Comment: The Closing event is triggered by the close command being called either in code or by clicking X in the control box. There is a chance that the developer may have wanted to cancel the close on the closing event with the custom code by invoking e.Cancel = True. Aside from that, close should not be called.

Comment: I would _think_ that at some point, it was done to perform logic that is done in the `Form.Close()` method. However, anything that needs to be performed in both places should be refactored to a separate method that can be called from both places (depending on how the native for event flow behaves).

Comment: Is there any chance that in this code refactoring you removed an overridden `Close()` function?

Comment: Is there a `return` statement somewhere inside a condition before the call to `Close();`? seems like an attempt to stop the closing of the form without using `e.Cancel = true;`.

Comment: No, there is no `return` statement somewhere. A colleague of mine tested a similar code and after 24 recursive calls on my computer (Windows 7) it exists the application. On his computer (Windows 10) it's after 30 recursive calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closing event is triggered when the form is about to close. You don't have to call the close method, as that is what invoked the event in the first place.

If you want the form to close, **simply do nothing**, since it will close when exiting the on closing callback.

If you want to prevent it from closing, you can write `e.Cancel = True`, which will prevent the form from closing.

Your college may have called the close method, because there were an overloaded version of it, but at some point got removed. Or maybe he/she wanted to close another form as well.
The important thing is, that **you don't need** to call that method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the programmer doesn't want to close this form. just need to looping the statement in side form_closing.
if want to close this form just remove or comment close() then it will working.
if you want to return the resource to computer you need to put Dispose() at the end of this method.